# ceil function with high precision

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer-division, ceil

How do I round up a number to the next integer with a high precision?

```
Input: var1 = (8193/4096) # var1 = 2.00024414063
Output: 3 # As an integer

>>> var1 = 8193/4096
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(var1)
2.0
>>> math.ceil(8193/4096)
2.0
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.ceil(8193/4096)
```

How can I elegantly do this operation?

Comment: Would `x/y + 1` be sufficient?

Comment: @ajcr what if `8192/4096`? I then would want the answer to be `2` and not `3`

Comment: I forgot to check for duplicates... gah. Well, it's closed now.

Comment: @Veedrac The duplicate question specifically asks for an `operator` for division used on `Python 3`. My question is asking for `precision` in `Python 2`.

Comment: @Sunil `What's` the `difference`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, this:

```
>>> var1 = 8193/4096
```

doesn't do what you think it does. In Python 2, dividing two integers always returns an integer (truncated) as the result.

```
>>> 8193/4096
2
```

...and then calling `math.ceil()` on 2 returns 2.

Convert one or both of your values to a floating point value and it will do what you like:

```
>>> v = 8193/4096.0
>>> v
2.000244140625
>>> math.ceil(v)
3.0
```

Alternatives:

a) switch to Python 3, where division does behave like you want it to:

```
bgporter@zappa:~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 8193/4096
2.000244140625
>>>
```

b) enable Python 3's division on Python 2 like this:

```
bgporter@varese ~:python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 8193/4096
2.000244140625
```

Comment: or `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Ah, good point. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**: You are currently doing integer division, which would implicitly compute the floor of the quotient and give you the Integer value.

**Solution**: Cast *one* of the elements (divisor or dividend) to a `float` first:

```
math.ceil( float(8193)/4096 ) 
3.0
```

*OR*: just *make* it a float by adding `.0` to the end of one of the numbers, like so:

```
math.ceil( 8193.0/4096 )
3.0
```

*OR*: import `division` feature from the `__future__` module to allow Python 3 division by default:

```
from __future__ import division
math.ceil( 8193.0/4096 )
```

**Python 3**: In Python 3, however, `/` is the true division, so you don't have to worry about above. There, if you want to replicate the issue that you are encountering, you would have to use `//` for the integer division. `//` functionality is the same across all Python version.

Comment: or `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 2):

```
-(-8193/4096)
```

does **exact** integer division, and rounds upwards.

It's thus way better than involving floats.

It's simply because `a/b` floors, so `-a/b` floors the negative, so `-(-a/b)`  gives you the answer you want.

To support Python 3 (always a good idea), use `-(-8193//4096)`.

---

Here's a quick example where it beats out `ceil`:

```
>>> -(-10**17 // 3)
33333333333333334
>>> int(ceil(10**17 / 3.0))
33333333333333332
```

Comment: I retract my previous criticism -- I'd missed that this was Python2. However this smacks of arcane symbols rather than pythonic programming. This is along the same lines of using `~~some_int` instead of `abs(some_int)`

Comment: Note that `//` works in Python 2 as well.

Comment: @AdamSmith `~~x` just gives `x`... Anyhow, I agree **but** it's sufficiently better than using floats that it's better to just wrap it in a function or comment it and live with the potential confusion. :)

Comment: @Veedrac oops you're right, `~~x` is `floor(x)` not `abs(x)`.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this approach. Premature optimization by introducing arcane double negation is the exact opposite of the kind of code I want to write (or maintain)

Comment: @AdamSmith Optimisation? I'm doing this for correctness. I find it easier to prove than Anton Savin's method because the edge cases are obvious.

Comment: Well, since the equivalent answer in the other question got lots of upvotes too, I guess we're not alone in liking this approach. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another pure integer way, for me a bit more intuitive than the approach with double negation, though it works only for positive `y`:

```
def myceil(x, y):
    return (x + y - 1) // y
```